# Make all sentences paragraphs in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have text in MS Word 2007. It is needed to make all sentences paragraphs. I can go over text and press Enter after each sentence but want to do it automatically. I am thinking about using Find/Replace Dialog. Need to replace end of sentence `.` to `.(new paragraph)`. Do you know how to write `(new paragraph)` symbol in the dialog?

Comment: See [How to put sentences on separate lines on Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190985/how-to-put-sentences-on-separate-lines-on-linux) (on U&L, naturally) for a lot of ideas on approaches to getting this right, and pitfalls to beware.  For example, you'll want to insert ¶ after `!` and `?` also, but not abbreviations (like "Mr. Spock" or "e.g.", for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Do you know how to write the new paragraph symbol ¶ in the Find/Replace dialog?

The **carriage return/paragraph mark** (¶) is represented by `^13` or `^p`.

---

#### Special characters you can use with Find and Replace in Word

> **Both "Find what" and "Replace with" Boxes**
>
> The following characters can be used in both the Find what and Replace with boxes. Other characters that be used in either the Find what box or the Replace with box are listed in the "'Find what' Box Only" and 
>   "'Replace with' Box Only" sections of this article.
>
> [image]

Source [Special characters you can use with Find and Replace in Word](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214204)